# client_max_body_size upload limit

Tags: git, bitbucket

i am trying to upload my files(300 MB) using git to bitbucket but git just hangs after showing a message recursion detected in die handler.

this is the error that i am getting:

error : RPC failed;

fatal : remote end hung up unexpectedly

fatal : recursion detected in die handler

i have tried this: git config http.postBuffer 524288000. But it is still not working.

i googled and i found that i have to change client_max_body_size. **Where and how can i change it?** Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing bitbucket does not allow you to upload such large files. Maybe with a paid plan you could do it. But storing such large files in a git repository is a bad idea anyway, git is not designed for that. You should use git-annexe or something instead.

Comment: thanks.. but just check this out : https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=273877699

Comment: Right, so although they didn't have any limits when that page was written, supposedly, they still say this kind of thing is a _really bad idea_.